Most efficient way to store dynamic properties in Django
Let's imagine we have a base like this:
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=25)
    # ... some other fields

    dynamic_properties = models.ManyToManyField("Dynamic")

class Dynamic(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_lenght=25)
    value = models.CharField(max_lenght=25)


MyModel would be the base of all my entries containing its base static data, but when ever I need to add a dynamic property I add it to the dynamic_properties field.
While this does make sense on the paper it's kinda inneficient from what's I've been testing so far, let's say each MyModel entries have an average of 4 dynamic properties if I want to iterate over 2k MyModel objects and return all their dynamic properties it is quite slow.
I tried to use prefetch_related as the docs suggest but it didn't seem to have a real impact (but that's maybe me misunderstanding how it's used).
For the reference I tried it like that:
{model.name: model.some_value for model in MyModel.objects.all()} # Is very slow
{model.name: model.some_value for model in MyModel.objects.prefetch_related("dynamic_properties")} # Is also very slow

Is there a more efficient way to have dynamic properties or is my understanding of prefetch_related wrong and this is the good way ?

You might want to show us how you're using prefetch_related, it should solve the N + 1 query problem you'd face (from what you describe), if things are still slow we'd need to see more code to be able to say why.
